# JavaScript select same row, multi columns (CSV)

Tags: javascript, p5.js

This is is P5.js and it's a very stupid and simple problem.
https://editor.p5js.org/kornfusion/sketches/5xtb88Ntn

```
  for (let i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
    for (let j = 0; j < table.getRowCount(); j++){
    if (table.getRow(i).arr[1] = '00:11:1F:AC:ba:39') {
      j = table.getRowCount(i).length;
      textSize(155);
      text(table.getRow(i).arr[2], 400, 540);
    }
  }
}
```

I'm trying to match the mac address with IP. and if they matched put them beside the circle. The circles are already in the sketch, All I need is the data from CSV file and go through each row to find MAC.

Comment: What does the “table” variable have to do with a csv?

Comment: What part are you having trouble with? Either a functional example or a detailed description of the problem would be very helpful.

Comment: I want to create a map from the CSV file where it shows 10 circles with the IP and MAC address on each circle..I want to extract IP and MAC from the CSV file and store them as variables so I can use them gloablly.

Comment: 1. You should give us more context on your code: you are calling a `text` function but I'm not sure you put that in the `draw()` function which would prevent showing anything 2. What are you trying to do with the second `for` loop with `j`, it looks like it shouldn't be there since you then assign another value to `j` and don't use it. 3. can you show us what the `table` object looks like? The `.arr[X]` syntax seems weird 4. All in all sharing [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will greatly help other people to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the info. i hope this would help:
https://editor.p5js.org/kornfusion/sketches/5xtb88Ntn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The description is confusing alongside the code.

> I'm trying to match the mac address with IP. and if they matched put them beside the circle.

Do you mean match a section of the MAC address to a section of the IP address ?

A MAC address in your example looks like this: `00:11:1f:10:11:13`.

An IP address in your example looks like this: `10.11.2.1`.

Do you mean compare the parts that aren't the same across rows (e.g. 00:**11**:1f:10:11:13 to **10**.11.2.1 )?

Your conditions suggests otherwise:

```
if (table.getRow(i).arr[1] = '00:11:1F:AC:ba:39')
```

It attempts to match any row with MAC address `00:11:1F:AC:ba:39`.
Notice that `arr[1]` points to the second CSV column: "Model".
The MAC address is the forth column (at index 3 (e.g. `table.getRow(i).arr[3]`))
Alternatively you can retrieve it by colum name since the CSV has a header:

```
table.getRow(i).obj["MAC address"]
```

If you're looping through all the rows a single for loop should do.
Additionally you need to handle the edge case of the MAC address not being in the list.

e.g.

```
  let foundIP = null;
  for (let i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++){
      let currentRow = table.getRow(i);
      if (currentRow.obj['MAC address'] === '00:11:1F:AC:ba:39'){
        foundIP = currentRow.obj['IP address'];
        break;
      }
    }

  
  if(foundIP){
    console.log('foundIP',foundIP);
  }else{
    console.log('no IP found for MAC 00:11:1F:AC:ba:39');
  }
```

Notice that:

- currentRow is re-used (as opposed to calling `table.get()` multiple times per loop): this pays off especially when you have to process many rows
- in JS `==` works, but `===` is recommended since it also checks if the data type matches
- `break` is used to break out of the for loop once a match has been found. (if it hasn't foundRow will not have a valid value)

This can easily be encapsulated in a re-usable function:

```
function findIP(table, macAddress) {
  for (let i = 0; i < table.getRowCount(); i++) {
    let currentRow = table.getRow(i);
    if (currentRow.obj['MAC address'] === macAddress) {
      return currentRow.obj['IP address'];
    }
  }
}
```

In this case, the result is either the IP (if found) or `undefined` (if no matches were found):

```
  let macToFind = '00:11:1F:AC:ba:39'
  let foundIP = findIP(table, macToFind);

  if (foundIP) {
    console.log('foundIP', foundIP);
  } else {
    console.log('no IP found for MAC ' + macToFind);
  }
```

This should make it flexible enough to search multiple tables and mac addresses if needed.